# Creating an Blazor (ASP.NET Core Hosted) project from template Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.0

It seems like a fairly easy Task, but for some reason Visual Studio does not show me any Blazor templates besides the server-side hosting model.

- My .Net Core version: `3.0.100-preview6-012264` from `dotnet --version`.
- My Visual Studio 2019 version: `16.1.6`.

[image]

Then I tried it in the CLI with the following command `dotnet new blazorhosted` like shown in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-3.0#client-side). It will only bring up the following error `No templates matched the input template name: blazorhosted.` and a list of available templates. But I did manage to create the 'client-side' hosting-model e.g. `dotnet new blazor`, which isn't displayed in VS as well.

I also tried to reinstall .Net Core Preview 6 as well as Visual Studio 2019, but with no success

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will need to first install the new blazor template:

```
dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates::3.0.0-preview6.19307.2
```